# Twig UTF-8 encoding of raw content

Tags: symfony, twig

A controller passes an array to a twig template. The array contains strings that correctly UTF-8 encoded. I can check this in the controller with `var_dump($theArray)`. All strings are displayed correctly.

But in twig

```
{% for video in videos %}
   {{ video.title_value | raw }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

some characters like `Ö,Ä,Ü` are replaced by this `�`. The controller and the template are encoded `UTF-8 without BOM` and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

is set. I have to do the raw output because the strings may contain html tags. Any idea how to fix the `�`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that your source data is actually UTF-8 encdoded. `var_dump()` alone isn't sufficient to verify the encoding of your content.

Try echoing/dumping the content and viewing the page with Firefox or Chrome and change the encoding to UTF-8 and then something else like ISO-8859-1. If your content looks wrong when you have UTF-8 selected then your content is not UTF-8 encoded.

- To change the encoding in Firefox: View > Character Encoding
- To change the encoding in Chrome: Tools > Encoding

Comment: if my contente looks different with ISO-8859-1, how is the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

the working solution for me was to follow the twig documentation 
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/convert_encoding.html

applying a filter {{ field|convert_encoding('UTF-8', ' iso-8859-1') }}

because this often happen when your sub- template is not inheriting the main one , where you had the correct meta charset defined

Comment: This does work but it's not a very handy solution. Any idea how to apply this globally?

Comment: yes true, but I've tried many other solutions and it did not worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and in my case the problem was database encoding mismatch. The solution for me was to use `utf8_encode()` when first inserting the data into database.

Sample from my code:

```
// Convert file name into title of template 
$name = str_replace(array('-', '_'), ' ', basename($file, ".html"));
$name = utf8_encode($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

mb_detect_encoding($str) is also a method to detect encoding.

http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding

Answer (score 0):

Try this filter: `convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')`

Comment: Please add some comment to your answer and explain why you are making this suggestion and why it could work. Code only answers are not really helpful for wider audience. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers